# In R, why is function "fviz_nbclust" not plotting when called inside a function?

Tags: r, function

I am trying to run the function `fviz_nbclust` inside a function but it does not plot the graphic.

If I run in Debbug mode and press `F10` on the `fviz_nbclust` line, it does not generate the graphic. But if I put the cursor on this line and press `Ctrl+Enter`, the graphic shows up.

Any clues?

Main code:

```
library(factoextra)

df <- cbind(rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1),rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1))
df
run_cluster(df)
```

Function code:

```
run_cluster <- function(df){

  fviz_nbclust(df, 
               FUNcluster = kmeans, 
               method = "wss", 
               k.max = nrow(unique(df)) - 1, 
               nstart = 2)

    return (T)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specifically print the plot it appears to work as expected; does this solve your problem?

```r
library(factoextra)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

df <- cbind(rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1),rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1))
head(df)
#>            [,1]       [,2]
#> [1,]  0.1046724 -1.2799086
#> [2,] -0.4395287 -0.8690895
#> [3,] -0.9810550 -1.1685272
#> [4,]  0.3313558  0.1799431
#> [5,]  0.3718252  2.5245255
#> [6,] -1.1644184  0.3907478

run_cluster <- function(df){
  
  kmeans_plot <- fviz_nbclust(df, 
               FUNcluster = kmeans, 
               method = "wss", 
               k.max = nrow(unique(df)) - 1, 
               nstart = 2)
  
  print(kmeans_plot)
}

run_cluster(df)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>